# How to see all your code reviews on github

Tags: github, github-codereviews

There's a way to filter all my code reviews on github?

I tried to follow docs, go to pull requests and then click on 'Review Requests', but i wasn't able to find a way to filter the code reviews i've done and see if there was any update on my comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github has a feature for this! Select `Reviewed by you` in the 'filter by reviews' dropdown

[image: screenshot of reviews dropdown]

You can also manually apply this filter by inputting this text in the filters input:

```
is:pr reviewed-by:@me
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar manner to viewing all review requests (`is:open is:pr review-requested:<username>`) you can view all PRs you have commented on like so:

```
is:pr commenter:username
```